# Excel renames the range of cells when using auto format for the table, how do I make that renamed range absolute?

Tags: microsoft-excel, lock

Not making the range ‘absolute’ yields incrementing results when copying the formula across cells:
I can create a table and a formula to count specific items that works:
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Name],"*",A2:A162,"*UBP")`

If I want to copy this formula across the same row, under several columns, it auto increments the column and the referenced range.
This =COUNTIFS(Table1[Name],"*",A2:A162,"*UBP")`
Becomes =COUNTIFS(Table1[Office],"*",B2:B163,"*UBP")

To make the A2:A162 absolute, I added the dollar signs and that works
This =COUNTIFS(Table1[Name],"*",$A$2:$A$163,"*UBP")
Becomes this =COUNTIFS(Table1[Office],"*",$A$2:$A$163,"*UBP")

When autoformatting, the cell range A2:A162 is renamed by excel, the formula became:
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Name],"*",Table1[Des],"*UBP")
I cannot make Table1[Des] absolute

Comment: Entering $ or adding F4 doesn't lock anything, it just makes a reference absolute. For table references, there is usually no need. So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It might be useful for you to explain what you are trying to achieve here (i.e. why you are trying to "lock" part of a formula)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy formulas with references to Table columns like this:

```
Table1[Name]
```

you can use `Copy`/`Paste` (or `Ctrl`+`C`/`Ctrl`+`V`) and then the reference will be treated as absolute.
You can also drag a formula and then this reference will be treated as relative.
If you want your reference be absolute when dragging use notation:

```
Table1[[Name]:[Name]]
```

Comment: Great answer. This article expands a bit more on the "double column name" technique:
https://www.excelcampus.com/tips-shortcuts/absolute-formula-references-excel-structured-table/